# There is an error in my python code (invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n')

Tags: python

**Broken code**
This code is  bigger than this this is just  the parts you  need to  understand it.
I have this  problem where when  i run it it gets to  the part of this  code and it  says in the console(invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n')

```
#setting position of unit
if int(number[3])== 0:
    unitpos=str(unit[0])

#printing number
if tenpos!='Ten' and unitpos!='one':
    print(thoupos+" \n "+hundpos+" \n "+andpos+" \n "+tenpos+" \n "+unitpos)
```

Comment: Well, what's `number[3]`?

Comment: Well, what's `number`?  `unit`?  `tenpos`? `unitpos`? `thoupos`? ...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that what you are passing to `if int(number[3])== 0:` in `number[3]` is the character `'\n'` and not a number.

This will produce the same error:

```
>>> if int('\n')== 0:
>>>     pass
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'
```

Without seeing more of your code, we can't tell you why there is a newline instead of a number.

Comment: @Chris "Invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'"